# Refresh jQuery datepicker calendar for "mousedown" of "next" and "prev" button instead of "click"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, datepicker

"prev" and "next" buttons in jQuery datepicker uses "click" event by default to trigger the update of calendar with new month.

Attached the below image to support the above point:

[image]

If I change "click" to "mousedown", the calendar is refreshed, but the datepicker widget closes immediately.

Is there a way to stop if from closing automatically while using "mousedown" event.

I wanted to change it to "mousedown" in order to make it work for right-click and also to increase the responsiveness of the widget.

NOTE: jQuery plugin version - v1.11.0

Comment: I think it has an option to close on date select. Did you check the available documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding additional `onmousedown` event to trigger the `click` event works.
To avoid it from closing, add `event.stopPropagation();`.

```
<a title="Next" .. id="next_id" onmousedown='var elId= "next_id";document.getElementById(elId).click();event.stopPropagation();' data-event="click" data-handler="next">
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can specify a version of the plugin, as I know there are more than one version. I had been working with some versions. Usually each good plugin has a callback functions, so you can try to use documentation to find callbacks and use one of them before some action. Making a trigger or code changes of the plugin can give you a bugs like you describing.